# 360 Rotation off setting

Tags: android, math, unity-game-engine, geometry

I am making a compass in android. I store the starting value of the z-axis.

As I rotate the phone in a circle, after every 10 degrees I want to make a decision.

I am calculating things as follows:

```
startingAngle=355;
currentAngle=`Real time value of z-axis`;
difference=currentAngle-startingAngle;

if(difference==10){
`enter code here`
}
```

When I start to rotate the phone in a circle, eventually `currentAngle` reaches 359, after which it goes to 1.

This raises a problem when `currentAngle` is 1 and `startingAngle` is 355 because `difference` becomes 344 but it should be 6.

How can I get the correct value of difference so I can trigger a function after 10 degrees?

Comment: What is your question? Nothing is clear.

Comment: @MBo the problem is that how to get the correct value of difference when the startingAngle is 335 and z the value of is 1   difference=startingAngle-valueof_z_axis  eg difference=355-3 => difference=352 but in reality that value is should be difference=8

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question right:

```
Diff  = Abs(Angle1 - Angle2)
if Diff >= 180
    Diff = 360 - Diff
```

Comment: what is Abs function and from which language it's belong

Comment: Absolute value - might be something like Math.Abs